# Proving homomorphism when group operation isn't specified?

Tags: group-theory

I'm using Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* for self-study, and I'm stuck on exercise B1 in chapter 14, which asks me to prove that some example functions are homomorphisms.  Based on the text, I believe this means showing that if $G$ and $H$ are groups and $\phi : G \rightarrow H$, then $\phi(a) + \phi(b) = \phi(a + b) \; \forall a,b \in G$, where '$+$' represents the group operation of $H$ on the left hand side of the equation and the group operation of $G$ on the right hand side.

Problem B1 defines the candidate homomorphism $\phi : \mathscr{F}(\Bbb{R})\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ given by $\phi(f) = f(0)$.

I assume $\mathscr{F}(\Bbb{R})$ is the set of all functions $f : \Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$, but this only gives the set of elements that make up the group $G$.  The operation on $G$ isn't specified.  Many example groups where the elements are functions use composition as the operation.  Is this implied whenever the elements are functions?  If so, I don't know how to prove $\phi(a) + \phi(b) = \phi(a \circ b)$ for arbitrary functions $a, b$.  If, on the other hand, the operation is addition, proving homomorphism is pretty trivial.  The operation on $\Bbb{R}$ isn't specified, but I'm gonna assume it's addition.

So the main question is, how can I determine what the operation of a group is when only the set of elements is given?  If the operation is composition in this case, then I could use at least a hint of how to proceed. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is any way to solve this  without knowing the group operation in $\mathscr{F}(\Bbb{R})$. I would try checking the index to see when this group is first mentioned in the group and see if they define a group operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the set of functions $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is not a group under composition. For example, let $f(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then clearly $f$ is not invertible. Associativity and identity are however satisfied.

The problem is indeed intended to be easy, and the intended operation is almost certainly addition.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\mathscr F(\mathbb{R})$ is usually given the following group structure: if $f, g $ are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then $f+g$ is the function $h: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$.